# When / How does Linux load shared libraries into address space?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, linker, shared-libraries

When is the address of shared objects specified in programs?  During linking?  Loading?  If I wanted to find the memory address of the `system` command inside of `libc` inside of my program I could find it easily in `gdb`, but what if I don't want to bring the program into a debugger?

Could this address change from run to run?  Are there any other static analysis tool that will allow be to view where libraries or functions will be loaded into this program's memory space when run?

I want this information outside of the program (ie. using utilities like `objdump` to gather information)

Comment: and then there's [`prelink`](http://people.redhat.com/jakub/prelink.pdf), which changes the order considerably.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Libraries are loaded by [`ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) (dynamic linker or run-time linker aka rtld, `ld-linux.so.2` or `ld-linux.so.*` in case of Linux; part of glibc). It is declared as "interpreter" (INTERP; `.interp` section) of all dynamic linked ELF binaries. So, when you start program, Linux will start  an `ld.so` (load into memory and jump to its entry point), then `ld.so` will load your program into memory, prepare it and then run it. You can also start dynamic program with

```
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./your_program your_prog_params
```

`ld.so` does an actual `open` and `mmap` of all needed ELF files, both ELF file of your program and ELF files of all neeeded libraries. Also, it fills GOT and PLT tables and does  relocations resolving (it writes addresses of functions from libraries to call sites, in many cases with indirect calls).

The typical load address of some library you can get with `ldd` utility. It is actually a bash script, which sets a debug environment variable of ld.so (actually `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1` in case of glibc's rtld) and starts a program. You even can also do it yourself without needs of the script, e.g. with using bash easy changing of environment variables for single run:

```
 LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /bin/echo
```

The `ld.so` will see this variable and will resolve all needed libraries and print load addresses of them. But with this variable set, `ld.so` will not actually start a program (not sure about static constructors of program or libraries). If the [ASLR feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is disabled, load address will be the same most times. Modern Linuxes often has ASLR enabled, so to disable it, use [`echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318315/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization).

You can find offset of `system` function inside the `libc.so` with `nm` utility from binutils. I think, you should use `nm -D /lib/libc.so` or `objdump -T /lib/libc.so` and grep  output.

Comment: wonderful information, thank you.  Do you know of any good articles that explain how this process works (generating GOT / PLT tables), or would googling yield sufficient results?

Comment: If you want to call a `system` with absolute address, you can do it without using a GOT and PLT tables. In my point, the best googling for `ld.so` is codesearch: http://google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=rtld_start+package%3Aglibc&sbtn=Search

Comment: Yes, I know you can do it without using GOT and PLT, it was mere curiosity on my part! :)

Comment: may be,... the book on linkers will help? http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker10.html Also there is a blog of author of `gold` linker and elf part of binutils ld linker www.airs.com/blog/archives/41

Comment: pdf of some blogposts from airs.com www.cs.pitt.edu/~abraham/CS0449/slides/Linking.pdf

Comment: This was very informative! I didn't know that much about ld.so and ldd!

Comment: This answer is incorrect in that `ld.so` does *not* load the main program, the kernel does. The kernel also doesn't look at any *sections* (which could be stripped completely), it finds the interpreter in `PT_INTERP` *segment*.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, Can you post more correct answer? I'm not expert in this and you is.

Answer (score 13):

"Go right to the source and ask the horse..."

[Drepper - How To Write Shared Libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Must-read documentation for Linux library writers. Explains the mechanics of loading in some detail.

Answer (score 10):

If you just want the address of a function while not hardcoding the name, you could `dlopen()` the main program:

```
void *self = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
dlsym(self, "system"); // returns the pointer to the system() function
```

If you just want the address of a function of which you know the name at compile-time, simply use `void *addr = &system;`

Comment: please see edit in OP, but definitely leave this answer as it is helpful for another variation of the potentially vague title. (how you answered it)

Comment: It's possible that neither will do what OP wants, since `system` is probably resolved to a PLT entry in the main program image that performs the actual jump into the shared library.

Answer (score 10):

The `nm` command, used on `libc.so`, will show you the location of the `system` symbol in `libc.so`. However, if ASLR is enabled, the address `libc.so` is loaded at, and thus the final address of `system` will vary randomly each time your program is run. Even without ASLR, you'll need to determine the address `libc.so` gets loaded at and offset the address of `system` by that amount.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I wanted - I'm assuming the best way to determine the offset of system within libc.so is to use nm again with the debugging symbols installed?  Or is there an easier / more robust manner to do this.

Comment: @Ryan, nm needs no debug symbols, it can read a symbol table directly (which is used by `ld.so`).

Comment: @osgx so then would my original question be correct, subtracting the debugging symbols?

Answer (score -1):

Id recommend that your environment have the LD_LIBRARY_PATH path. This defines where the shared libraries are to be found. You may also have to look into /etc/ld.so.conf
Look at this posting http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCQQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fubuntuforums.org%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D324660&ei=KqJpTey7JofEsAPE9_imBA&usg=AFQjCNEIbGGrTHp4fufRuj4Yfc58RTHcag&sig2=_9tdlyadMbPc-FcOdCko-w