# How do *.so files work, and where do they go in UNIX?

Tags: python, linker, cx-freeze

I've recently been "compiling" python scripts into binary form for the purpose of internal distribution. I'm using the utility cx_freeze which, in it's default state, creates a directory with the primary binary executable in it as well as a bunch of binary *.so files. My understanding is that .so files are libraries, and they are obviously necessary to get the executable binary to function, but my question is how can I link stuff together so they don't all have to be in the same directory? Do I have to determine that at "compile time"? Is there a universal path variable that the executables will look in for libraries it might need, or is that path stated somewhere in the executable itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate / closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130654/when-how-does-linux-load-shared-libraries-into-address-space

Answer (score 4):

The shared objects are searched for by the dynamic linker in a number of locations as explained in the dynamic linker's manpage for [linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) or [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html):

1. `DT_RPATH` attribute stored in the binary for ELF files.
2. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable if the executable isn't set-user-id/set-group-id.
3. `DT_RUNPATH` attribute stored in the binary for ELF files.
4. `/etc/ld.so.cache` file which serves as library path cache for the dynamic linker.
5. Finally, the default directories `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Okay, so if cx_Freeze gives me a bunch of .so files, I would think I could just throw them in /lib and the linker would be able to find them? But that doesn't work. It seems like I should be able to specify something at compile time pointing it to the shared object files?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Putting the libraries in /lib should work. You can use ldd command to see which libraries are picked up and from where. I don't know which compiler you're using, but it is highly likely it has the flags you're looking for. Check compiler's documentation. If you're using gcc check out -l and -L.