# Dynamic library in Linux

Tags: linux, gcc

When we creating a binary using the Dynamic library we apply `gcc -o binary main.o -L. -lmylib -Wl,-rpath,.` where `-L.` indicate that linker must search library in current directory. Why without `-Wl,-rpath,.` we can't use the dynamic library?

Comment: Have you read 'man ld.so'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several directories in the system where ld.so looks for libraries. If your library is not in a directory from that list, you have two alternatives:

- Specify path to it in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable;
- Write path to it in the `rpath` of the binary.

You can change/view rpath of the binary using `chrpath`.

Difference betwee `-rpath` and `-L`:

```
-rpath=dir
      Add a directory to the runtime library search path. This is used
      when linking an ELF executable with shared objects. All -rpath
      arguments are concatenated and passed to the runtime linker, which
      uses them to locate shared objects at runtime.
```

vs.

```
-L searchdir
--library-path=searchdir
      Add path searchdir to the list of paths that ld will search for
      archive libraries and ld control scripts.
```

( [What's the difference between -rpath and -L?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482152/whats-the-difference-between-rpath-and-l) )

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one doubt: Is it true that when we use  shared object (.so) linker is dynamically uploaded a corresponding object file when it needs or all objects file uploaded after beginnig execution?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130654/when-how-does-linux-load-shared-libraries-into-address-space

Answer (score 0):

By default, `ld.so` searches in the directories specified by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If your shared lib isn't in one of those, it won't be found.

The `-rpath` option to `ld` causes it to store a pathname in the executable that `ld.so` will look in.