# What's the rule of dynamic library searching for ld?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, ld

Linux separates the linker-time search path and run-time search path.

For the run-time search path, I found the rule for `ld.so` in its [man page (8 ld.so)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html):

1. DT_RPATH
2. environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH
3. DT_RUNPATH
4. ld.so.cache
5. /lib, /usr/lib

But for linker-time search path, no luck for `ld` :(

[Man page for `ld` (1 ld)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) says, besides `-L` option:

> The default set of paths searched (without being specified with `-L`) depends on which emulation mode ld is using, and in some cases also on how it was configured.
>
> The paths can also be specified in a link script with the "`SEARCH_DIR`" command.  Directories specified this way are searched at the point in which the linker script appears in the command line.

Does the "default set of paths" depending on emulation mode mean "`SEARCH_DIR`"?

Comment: misssprite, what is the "ld"? Is it "ld.so", or is it "ld-linux.so" or "libdl.so"? ["ld-linux.so"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) (ELF dynamic linker / loader) is registered as interpreter in the dynamic ELF file, section... [INTERP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5130690/196561), check `readelf -l ./dynamic_application`. PS Which man page you used, is it http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html or some other?

Comment: I mean the `linker` in GCC, not the loader. I'll edit it.@osgx

Comment: misssprite, your understanding of man page 1 ld http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html is incorrect, DT_RPATH and other are used for searching dynamic libraries (they are named `libSOMETHING.so` like `libc.so`), required by the application with NEEDED entries of the dynamic section (check output of `readelf -d ./dynamic_program`). There is no dynamic library named `ld.so`.

Comment: I know `ld.so` is the LOADER, not a .so library.. Maybe you can help me edit the question to fix anywhere confusing.@osgx

Comment: dynamic libraries are searched (in run-time) by dynamic loader ld-linux.so as you described in the question. And ld-linux.so path (at end of compile+link process) is hardcoded in the binutils linker `ld` (incorrectly) and in gcc (correctly, check `gcc -dumpspecs|grep dynamic-linker`), and passed from gcc to ld (check my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about the `ld` itself, the library path search order is the following:

1. Directories specified via `-L` command line flags
2. Directories in the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable
3. `SEARCH_DIR` variables in the linker script.

You can look what directories are specified in the default linker script by running `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR`. Note that `=` in the `SEARCH_DIR` values will be replaced by the value of `--sysroot` option if you specify it.

Usually `ld` is not invoked directly, but via compiler driver which passes several `-L` options to the linker. In the case of `gcc` or `clang` you can print the additional library search directories added by a compiler by invoking it with `-print-search-dirs` option. Also note that if you specify some machine-specific compiler flags (like e.g -m32 as [misssprite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008532/misssprite) mentioned) than the linker may use different linker script according to the chosen ELF emulation. In the case of `gcc` you can use `-dumpspecs` option to look how different compiler flags affect the linker invocation. But IMHO the simplest way to look for the linker command line is to compile and link a simple program with `-v` specified.

Comment: LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work for me. I edited the question to clarified the question. Can you update responding to the two issues? By the way, I didn't mention `-m32`. It seems that another buddy removed his answer.

Comment: @misssprite, what was your exact command which you tried to modify with LIBRARY_PATH? I see no reads of LIBRARY_PATH in ld sources in binutils: https://github.com/bneumeier/binutils/search?q=LIBRARY_PATH&type=Code and `ldfile_add_library_path` https://github.com/bneumeier/binutils/search?q=ldfile_add_library_path+ is filled with SEARCH_DIR options of linker script (https://github.com/bneumeier/binutils/blob/db980de65ca9f296aae8db4d13ee884f0c18ac8a/ld/ldgram.y#L328) and ld `-L options` https://github.com/bneumeier/binutils/blob/db980de65ca9f296aae8db4d13ee884f0c18ac8a/ld/ldfile.c#L569

Comment: @osgx, the command should be OK, `export LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LIBRARY_PATH`. So the src code also indicates that LIBRARY_PATH does not take effect.

Comment: @osgx, so all the things related are SEARCH_DIR and -L?

Comment: @misssprite, this is not full command, this is only changing of LIBRARY_PATH. How you started `ld` and which `ld` options were used?

Comment: @osgx, I run `ld hello.o -ltest -L.` and `ld hello.o -ltest`, with LIRARY_PATH set. The former found the `libtest.so` in pwd, and the latter didn't.

Comment: @misssprite, and what is your OS, is it ubuntu? Is your ld from gnu binutils?

Comment: @osgx, yes, it's ubuntu gnu ld. As you stated previously, `LIBRARY_PATH` does not appear in the ld source, it should not take effect. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

[misssprite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008532/misssprite), to look for the linker search path for specific ELF emulation just run `ld -m<emulation> --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR`

Answer (score 0):

misssprite, there is no search for `ld.so` or `ld-linux.so` in the binutils's ld linker.

When dynamic program is build with gcc, it uses option `-dynamic-linker` of ld (collect2) program: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html

> `-Ifile`, `--dynamic-linker=file`
>
> ```
>   Set the name of the dynamic linker.  This is only meaningful when
>        generating dynamically linked ELF executables.  The default
>        dynamic linker is normally correct; don't use this unless you
>        know what you are doing.")
> ```

Usually used as runtime loader for ELF, the "ld-linux.so" is registered as interpreter in the dynamic ELF file, program header `INTERP` (`.interp`), check output `readelf -l ./dynamic_application`. This field is for full path, as I understand.

When there is no gcc (directly called 'ld' program) or no this option was given, `ld` uses hardcoded string of full path to `ld.so`; and this default is incorrect for most OS, including Linux:

https://github.com/bneumeier/binutils/blob/db980de65ca9f296aae8db4d13ee884f0c18ac8a/bfd/elf64-x86-64.c#L510

```
/* The name of the dynamic interpreter.  This is put in the .interp
   section.  */

#define ELF64_DYNAMIC_INTERPRETER "/lib/ld64.so.1"
#define ELF32_DYNAMIC_INTERPRETER "/lib/ldx32.so.1"
```

https://github.com/bneumeier/binutils/blob/db980de65ca9f296aae8db4d13ee884f0c18ac8a/gold/x86_64.cc#L816

```
template<>
const Target::Target_info Target_x86_64<64>::x86_64_info =
 ...
  "/lib/ld64.so.1",     // program interpreter
const Target::Target_info Target_x86_64<32>::x86_64_info =
 ...
  "/libx32/ldx32.so.1", // program interpreter
```

Correct dynamic linker/loader path is hardcoded in machine [spec files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) of gcc, grep output of `gcc -dumpspecs` command for ld-linux for `-dynamic-linker` option value.

Comment: Specs and ld.so paths are hardcoded in gcc sources here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/search?q=-dynamic-linker&type=Code  & https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/search?q=GLIBC_DYNAMIC_LINKER in gcc/config/*/*.h files: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1cb6c2eb3b8361d850be8e8270c597270a1a7967/gcc/config/i386/linux.h  gcc/config/i386/linux.h `#define GLIBC_DYNAMIC_LINKER "/lib/ld-linux.so.2"` & https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/700a97608cadfe8adcd1a98e6388a5cbee9d76f6/gcc/config/i386/linux64.h gcc/config/i386/linux64.h `#define GLIBC_DYNAMIC_LINKER64 "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of how `ld` locates `ld-linux.so` when linking. But my real question is "what does 'the default set of paths' mean in man page for `ld` for searching .so?"